# PHP Google Search Console API "invalid_grant" response

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-search-api, google-search-platform

I am using following PHP code to fetch data through Google Search Consonle API.

It was working fine 2 months ago but now it's showing invalid grand message instead of data. Please! need your help.

```
 error: '400 - {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Bad Request"}'
```

I've right credentials included. Also you can see token is saved in file and is being fetched on demand and getting refresh too. I don't why it's stopped working.

Thanks

At the top I've added

```
 use Google_Client;
 use Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest;
 use Google_Service_Webmasters;
```

and here is the code

```
$siteToFetch = (!empty($site)) ? base64_decode($site) : "https://www.siteiamfulluserof.com/";


$client_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX-FULL-TOKEN-REMOVED';
$client_secret = 'xxxxxx-xxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx';
$redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/redirect_url';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->setAuthConfig(public_path("client_secret_latest.json"));
$client->setScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters", 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly');

if (file_exists($this->tokenFile)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($this->tokenFile), true);
} else {
    // Request authorization from the user.
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

    if (isset($_REQUEST['code'])) {
        $authCode = $_REQUEST['code'];
        // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
        $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

        if (!file_exists(dirname($this->tokenFile))) {
            mkdir(dirname($this->tokenFile), 0700, true);
        }

        file_put_contents($this->tokenFile, json_encode($accessToken));
    } else {
        exit('No code found');
    }
}

$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

// Refresh Token if expired.
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $refreshTokenSaved = $client->getRefreshToken();
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refreshTokenSaved);
}


if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

    $googleQuery = new \Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest();

    $googleQuery->setStartDate(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-180 days')));
    $googleQuery->setEndDate(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 days')));
    $googleQuery->setDimensions(['page', 'date']);
    $googleQuery->setSearchType('web');

    try {

        $service = new Google_Service_Webmasters($client);

        $response = $service->searchanalytics->query($sitesFetched[0]["site"], $googleQuery);

        $siteData = [];

        foreach ($response as $row) {
            $siteData[] = [
                "site" => $row->keys[0],
                "date" => $row->keys[1],
                "clicks" => $row->clicks,
                "impressions" => $row->impressions,
                "ctr" => $row->ctr,
                "position" => $row->position,
            ];
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $error = json_decode($e->getMessage());
        if ($error->error = "invalid_grant") {
            echo "You don't have proper permissions to access this site or data is being fetched.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the full error message.  Invalid grant what? there should be more to it then that.    there are around 10 causes for invalid grant the full message will give us a better idea what the issue is.

Comment: @DaImTo I've edited my question and included the result. Waiting for your solution now.

Comment: Still not enough try deleting the refresh token and requesting a new one.  See if that fixes it

Comment: Already tried. Why still not enough? Any part of code missing, or what?

Comment: your still getting invalid grant after deleting the tokenFile and requesting access again?

Comment: are you sure this ever worked your not even loading the refresh token anywhere.

Comment: Yes! still the same. I don't know what changed because it was working fine before.

Comment: @DaImTo. you mean this `$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);`?

Comment: again delete the file denoted by **$this->tokenFile**  Does your app request authorization again?